# Turn off Control+=

Tags: front-end, customization

I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> at least once a week and it always takes forever to load and is generally useless. I know SW likes it because he uses it all the time in the livestreams, but I truly hate it. I'll make a new WA cell if I want that.

Most recently it entirely crashed the PresenterTools system because I accidentally hit it and the letter P.

Is it possible to easily disable or do I have to go to `KeyEventTranslations.tr`?

Comment: This annoys me also. Good to know that I am not alone! Even more annoying: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> at the beginning of an input cell. This cannot be undone by using backspace and really disturbs the flow!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I also don't particularly like that one. On the other hand it's actually nice enough to fix. Look at `StyleKeyMapping`. You can unset that one for `Input` at the stylesheet level and never see it again :)

Answer (score 11):

[image]

> {$InstallationDirectory} / SystemFiled / FrontEnd / TextResources / {OS} / MenuSetup.tr

One can set it up on a corresponding path in `$UserBaseDirectory` (search around for MenuSetup.tr or KeyEventsTranslation.tr topics to see details).

Then delete `MenuKey[..]` part and done.

Unless we can find a FE option which governs that shortkey I don't think there is other solution.

If it was a front end token or we knew the MenuCommand associated with that action we could:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd,
  FrontEndEventActions :> {
    {"MenuCommand",(*Inline Free-form Input*)} :> {}}
]
```

but it is not the case. Fortunately editing menu setup works well.

Comment: On a Mac, this file seems to be `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", "Macintosh", "MenuSetup.tr"}]`